# How to redirect Windows cmd output from local machine to remote file via ssh

Tags: windows, ssh, command-line-interface

How can I redirect Windows cmd output from a local (windows) machine to a remote machine and save the output as file via ssh.

For example something like this: `cmd /C "hostname | ssh user@host cat > remotefile.txt"` This is writing 'hostname' as text to remotefile.txt instead of the command output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the same command, without cmd and with stdin descriptor (as [seen here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34274/7490)), would work

```
hostname | ssh user@host "cat - > remotefile.txt"
```